# Docker mariadb and django

Tags: django, docker

I have up and running docker image for MariaDB10.4.11. when i connect with django project it gives me following error:

**django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'172.18.0.4' (using password: YES)")**

I can login into MariaDB with same credential, which I am using in setting.py file.

This is my docker-compose file configuration.

```
db:
    image: mariadb:10.4.11
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: bookstore
      MYSQL_USER: bs
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: xxxxx
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: xxxx

    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
    - mariadb_data:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  mariadb_data:
```

Any help will highly appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: There is an open bug: https://github.com/docker-library/mariadb/issues/262. If you wait a ong time (took about 5 minutes on my test), the db and user will eventually be initialized. Until then, mariadb runs on temporary server where root has an empty password.

Comment: There seems to be a workarround with `MYSQL_INITDB_SKIP_TZINFO=1` but you have to add TZ data yourself if you need it.

Comment: I appreciate your quick reply, so what should I do can you please type step by step command. Thanks

Comment: Did you read the above bug report and the discussion ? More specifically this message ? https://github.com/docker-library/mariadb/issues/262#issuecomment-566018820